# Could someone explain how this works: const print = @import("std").debug.print;

Tags: zig

How can this const print variable behave like a function?

```
const print = @import("std").debug.print;
print("hello, world", .{});
```

I understand you can assign expressions to variables. But this seems to behave like a precompiler macro in c/c++, I  wouldn't have guessed that.
Is it because *"all variables declared in a comptime expression are implicitly comptime variables"* and @ makes it a comptime expression, so it is evaluated before compilation, much like a macro would in c?
Could someone elaborate a bit? This seems a very powerful feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` does not indicate a comptime expression; rather `@` prefixes built-in functions in Zig. `@import` returns a struct that provides access to the declarations made public by the imported file.

The expression `@import("std").debug.print` evaluates to the `print` function defined in the standard library file [`std/debug.zig`](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/master/lib/std/debug.zig); it is not the *expression* that is assigned to `print` in the posted code, but the *function*. That is, the posted code works because `print` in OP code is actually a function. This can be seen by running the code below:

```
const print = @import("std").debug.print;

pub fn main() void {
    print("@TypeOf print: {}\n", .{ @TypeOf(print) });
}
```

Results:

```
$ zig run print_type.zig 
@TypeOf print: fn(comptime []const u8, anytype) void
```

### Function Assignment

OP has asked for another example of assigning a function that is not imported to an identifier:

```
const print = @import("std").debug.print;

fn my_function(msg: []const u8) void {
    print("{s}\n", .{ msg });
}

const my_function_alias = my_function;

pub fn main() void {
    const another_function_alias = my_function;
    const yet_another_function_alias = my_function_alias;

    my_function("mf");
    my_function_alias("mfa");
    another_function_alias("afa");
    yet_another_function_alias("yafa");
}
```

Program output:

```
$ zig run function_assignment.zig 
mf
mfa
afa
yafa
```

Comment: seems the print function itself evaluates to the writer function defined somewhere else:

`pub fn print(comptime fmt: []const u8, args: anytype) void {
    stderr_mutex.lock();
    defer stderr_mutex.unlock();
    const stderr = io.getStdErr().writer();
    nosuspend stderr.print(fmt, args) catch return;
}
`

So I can assign not only the result but the actual function to a variable? Could you perhaps add a small example of how to achieve this in local code, so without @importing the function from external file?

Comment: @Gaai -- I added another example of assigning a function to a variable. "_seems the print function itself evaluates to the writer function...._" I wouldn't say that `print` evaluates to a writer function, but that `print` calls a writer function.